# Sync-fusion Blazor dynamic query not working

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion

I used template grid function of sync-fusion but the dynamic query is not working.

[image: My Code for creating grid using dynamic query]

So any one have any idea what i did wrong in this query ?

Thank you.
Note : I am using version 17.3.0.21-beta with Blazor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

From our **2019 Volume 4 release (17.4.0.39)** only we have changed the type of **Query** property to **Query** class. Before that release, type of Query property will be string. Kindly refer the below release notes about the changes we have done in our Grid for your reference

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/release-notes/17.4.39/#grid

So kindly upgrade to latest version (17.4.0.42  - because we have fixed the many breaking issue after that main release) to resolve the reported query. Also ensure to import the Syncfusion Blazor Data instance in your sample project.

```
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.Blazor
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.Blazor.Buttons
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.Blazor.Data
@using Syncfusion.EJ2.Blazor.Grids


If you want to use the same approach in 17.3.0.21-beta version, then kindly specify the query property value in form of string (like below). 

<EjsGrid ModelType="Model" DataSource="@Employees" Height="315px">
    <GridTemplates>
        <DetailTemplate>
            @{
                var employee = (context as EmployeeData);             
                <EjsGrid DataSource="@Orders" Query="@QueryData(employee)">
. . . . . . 
                </EjsGrid>
            }
        </DetailTemplate>
    </GridTemplates>
. . . . . . .. . . 
</EjsGrid>

@code{
    public int? Val { get; set; }
    public EmployeeData Model = new EmployeeData();
    public string QueryData(EmployeeData employee)
    {
        return $"new ej.data.Query().where('EmployeeID', 'equal', {employee.EmployeeID})";
    }  
. . . . . . . .. 

    public class EmployeeData
    {
        public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
        . . . . . . . . . 
    }
}
```